# Why is my gameObject not visible with structure mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I generate a dynamic mesh and materials for an object. Mesh of objects like this: http://prntscr.com/8z98f4. And in the scene it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/8z98hk. Why does the object draw with cavity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not defined the normals of your mesh?

You could do this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateNormals.html

Or calculate the normals yourself and set them like this:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-normals.html